# Obtain the Dot Net Core Framework Location from a Bundled Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-4.0, windows-services, .net-assembly

I am creating a Windows Service under Dot Net Core 5.0 and publishing it as a "single file executable" as described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service#publish-the-app

My service needs to get the folder of its executable, which I do by calling `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);`  However, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?view=net-5.0#remarks

> In .NET 5.0 and later versions, for bundled assemblies, the value
> returned is an empty string.

Which is what I am experiencing when I install and start the service.  So I work around this by using `Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);` instead, which works to get me the folder of the service's .exe file.

HOWEVER:  My app is compiling C# code and I need to add references to the Dot Net Core Framework folder.  To get the folder of the framework I am calling `typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location` which works EXCEPT when running from a "bundled" Windows Service.

How can I obtain the path to the Dot Net Core framework when running as a Bundled Windows Service?

Answer (score 0):

A `CSharpCompilation` needs a `MetadataReference` for each assembly. You can obtain one for an assembly without knowing the location as follows;

```cs
public static ModuleMetadata GetMetadata(this Assembly assembly)
{
    // based on https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36590#issuecomment-689883856
    unsafe
    {
        return assembly.TryGetRawMetadata(out var blob, out var len)
            ? ModuleMetadata.CreateFromMetadata((IntPtr)blob, len)
            : throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not get metadata from {assembly.FullName}");
    }
}

AssemblyMetadata.Create(assembly.GetMetadata()).GetReference();
```

That way you can reference all the assemblies you have deployed in your single file executable. Either explicitly based on some type like `typeof(object).Assembly` or filtered from `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`.

Note that you'll need to reference both the netstandard and Runtime assemblies, which don't define any types. But you can identify them by their `.FullName`.

Comment: I expected to do something like ```AssemblyMetadata.Create(typeof(object).Assembly.GetMetadata()).GetReference()``` but an Assembly does not have a ```.GetMetadat()``` method.  Also, ```AssemblyMetadata.Create()``` wants ModuleMetadata not AsemblyMetadata.  What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, right. I forgot that was an extension method I wrote myself based on a github comment :/.