# An exception that occurs after.NET Core is compiled to a single file

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, compilation

There's code in the program that looks something like this

```
            var references = dbType.Assembly
            .GetReferencedAssemblies()
            .Select(e => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load(e).Location))
            .Union(new MetadataReference[]
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load("netstandard").Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load("System.Runtime").Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(ModelSnapshot).Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(dbType.Assembly.Location)
            });
```

Under normal circumstances, debugging and publishing are fine, but when I compile the program into a file, an exception occurs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNjfI.png)

When using CreateFromStream

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiQ0j.png)

When using MetadataReference. CreateFromFile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI5Uv.png)

How should this problem be solved？

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69818433/4139809